# How to read from a file, find some word, modify it and save the file?

Tags: php

I want to read from a file, find some word and modify it and save the file. The file format (like spaces and newline ) changes after modification. How to do it?

```
  <?php
   $f = file_get_contents("conf1.tcf", "r");
   $arr = preg_split('/\s+/', $f);

   for($i=0 ;$i < sizeof($arr) ;$i++)
   {
   if($arr[$i] == "something")
   then edit;
   }
   $f1= implode(" ",$arr);
   file_put_contents("conf1.tcf", $f1);
   $fileo = fopen("conf1.tcf", "r");

   while(!feof($fileo)) 
   {
   echo fgets($fileo) . "<br />";
   }
   fclose($fileo);
    ?>
```

Comment: Show your coding effort. we can help if problem occurs?

Comment: Here's a [starting point](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) for you

Answer (score 0):

To get the content you can use `file_get_contents($filename)`.

Then to write the file `file_put_contents($filename, $content)`.